# Knapsack for table

Tags: dynamic-programming

I have a problem that I can't solve. There is this
[table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1wkK.png)

I have to optimaly allocate 1 million dollars among the five products. I think it looks like knapsack problem but I am not sure. If I want to solve this for what should I look? If it is knapsack how should I change an original knapsack solution to fit mine problem? Thank you.

Comment: It should be bruteforceable, by writing some code to try all combinations. Not fun or smart, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

These return functions are all monotonically increasing.  Use hill-climbing.

Start with \$200k allocated to each product, an allocation of $(2,2,2,2,2)$.  Your largest increment is with product E ($0.65 - 0.45 = 0.2$).  Your smallest decrement is with product B ($0.30-0.18 = 0.12$).  So your new allocation is $(2,1,2,2,3)$.

You have an unallocated \$80k, but that's not enough to purchase an increment.  Now find the remaining largest increment and smallest decrement pair, apply them.  You'll have more than \$100k unallocated with which you acquire one more largest increment (without a decrement).

Repeat until no more increment/decrement pairs remain and you do not have enough unallocated to just increment the allocation to a product.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but how should I allocate money if there are several products which increment and decrement are the same, like A and B product increment is 15 and it is the biggest one? Should I check even further increments decrements or just try all possibilities from here?

Comment: @R.Vait : When multiple increments are possible, use the one whose subsequent increment is largest.  When multiple decrements are possible, use the one whose subsequent decrement is smallest.  Recurse as needed.